# How to do Dynamic Proxying to Kubernetes Pods?

Tags: docker, http, nginx, kubernetes, proxy

I'm wanting to create a service that can do some kind of dynamic proxying back to Kubernetes Pods. Basically I'll have hundreds of K8s Pods that are running the same application that map to a random port on the host (like `10456`). However, each Pod is unique and I want traffic directed at a specific pod based on hostname. So when a request comes in for `abc123.app.com`, I'll have a proxy layer that does a lookup in a database to find what host and port that domain is running on (like `10.0.0.5:10456`), then forward the request there. Is there a service that supports this? I've worked with Nginx a lot before, but I'm not clear if it could support this lookup functionality.

Has anyone built something like this before? what's the best way to build a proxy layer that can do lookups like that? How would I update the database when a pod moves from one host to another?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I should have put this in there the first time, but the types of traffic going to these pods are RPC traffic and Peer to Peer traffic

Comment: https://istio.io/ can help you

Comment: Is this all http traffic?

Comment: Ah, should have put that in the post. The application uses RPC and a P2P protocol.

Comment: You'll need a proxy that understands those protocols then, sounds like you may need to roll your own unless it's something common. kubernetes can cover the pod lookup , but only mapping of a hostname for http.

Comment: If you can add some pseudo code of how the two protocols come in and how they are forwarded people might be able to help

Answer (score 2):

You're describing something very similar to what kubernetes [ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) definitions do for http traffic.

An ingress definition configures an [ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/) to point requests for a hostname at a [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/). The [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) selects endpoints (pods) via [label selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/). When pods move, kubernetes updates the service automatically.

The work on your end just becomes pushing out config changes from your database via one of the [API clients](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) to kubernetes rather than directing a proxy. If your environment was extremely dynamic requiring reconfiguration all the time or you need to make dynamic decisions about where traffic should go, you might want to continue looking at a custom proxy or [istio](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/request-routing/), [openresty](https://openresty.org/en/dynamic-routing-based-on-redis.html).

It sounds like you have unique deployments going to kubernetes already, so in addition to that include a service and ingress definition.

A simple example including a label on the a pod, a service that use the label. Then an ingress definition using the service.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-app
  labels:
    app: host-abc123
spec:
  containers:
  - name: host-abc123
    image: me/my-app:1.2.1
    ports:
    - containerPort: 10456
```

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: host-abc123
spec:
  rules:
  - host: abc123.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: host-abc123
          servicePort: 80
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: host-abc123
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 10456
```

The single ingress definition could include all hosts but I'm not sure how kubernetes and the ingress controllers would go replacing that regularly.

There are [nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) based ingress controllers too. You end up with a nginx `server` config per ingress/host definition.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Matt! I’ll research these Kubernetes primitives more and see if they can do the job for me. But do these work for non HTTP traffic?

Comment: The ingress resource is specific to http